# In React Native SectionList, how do I put a view on top of another view, with part of it lying outside the bounds of the view behind?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I'm trying to make a layout as per below with React Native SectionList https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html.

A is a header component, B is inside the header and the empty space white component below is a row.

[image]

How do I specify the position of B relative to A?

You can achieve this easily on iOS with position relative or absolute and let the view (B) inside the header overflow the View (A). However android does not support overflow. Short of writing my own list I am a little stuck.

Comment: try with a negative value of margin-top.

Comment: No luck, but  your comment is unclear.